# Application of the spectral decomposition theorem to PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

In the compact version, there is many application of the spectral decomposition of a bounded self-adjoint operator: Sturm-Liouville, spectre of the laplacian,...

But for the general version which insure that up to decompose the Hilbert space into a countable sum of subspace, your operator $T$ is equivalent to a multiplication on a certain $L^2(Sp(T),\mu)$ on each factor. In every books i know, they give as application the functional calculus for Borel functions. But does anyone know nice application to PDE?

Comment: I cannot answer, but I can point to a blog post by T.Tao which addresses the issue: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/

Comment: The general decomposition occurs when the operator is non-compact. For example, laplacian defined on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, or on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2}-{(0,0)})$.